# How to get the div value javascript php html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Myhtml:

```
<form id="w" action="modify_review.php?act=transmitNext" method="POST">
<input id="title" name="title" value="" />
<div class="selected_staff" id="selected_staff" name="editor"></div>
</form>
```

modify_review.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["title"];//works fine
echo $_POST["editor"];//failed
?>
```

How can i get the div value in myphp? who can help me ?

Comment: Without javascript - you cannot. Second question is why div? Why not another `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to achieve this.

1. You can use `textarea`.
2. Use JavaScript to get the value with existing code structure (just one hidden input field need to be added).

   - Add hidden input by following attrs.
     input type: `hidden`
     name: editor
     `Id=selectedStuff`
   - bind `getSelectedStuff` method on `onchange` on div `id=selected_stuff`

     ```
     function getSelectedStuff(userInput){
         // get user input
         var inputValue = userInput.value;
         //set value to hidden input
         document.getElementById("selectedStuff").value = inputValue;
     }
     ```